# Foreign key constraint with text reference

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, mariadb

I have a general purpose lookup table with three columns: id, type and value.

```
CREATE TABLE `lookup` (
    `lookup_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `type` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `value` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`lookup_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `lookup_id` (`lookup_id`, `type`),
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I have another table

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
    `foo_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `lookup_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`foo_id`),
    INDEX `foo_id` (`foo_id`),
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I want to create a multi column foreign key to the lookup table from the second table that references both the lookup_id and the lookup.type. However the child table only has a column for the id. The type is implicit. I would like to create a foreign key constraint that makes the type explicit. Is it possible to do this?

Something like this, only this doesn't work.

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_lookup` FOREIGN KEY (`lookup_id`, 'foo_type') REFERENCES `lookup` (`lookup_id`, `type`),
```

(note that foo_type is a string and not a column name)

Comment: you can't use strings as foreign keys. That's just totally non-sensical. And what's the point of adding the `foo_type` anyways? `lookup_id` in the lookup table is already the primary key.

Comment: The lookup table is a general purpose lookup table that many tables use to reference options that would otherwise require their own table (we're talking dozens of very small tables, each with only 2 or 3 rows.). The type distinguishes between different types of lookup. Being able to create a foreign key constraint to it would increase referential integrity

Comment: no, it wouldn't. lookup_id is a primary key, which means it's a UNIQUE key. pointing at a particular record in lookups means there can only ever be one type associated with that record. storing a `foo_type` in your child table would lead to situations where the the parent record says `(42,'bar')`, and your child table says `(42,'banana')`.

Comment: Yes, table foo uses the unique primary key, however the only legal values are defined by the type column, which would have 'foo_type' in it. Table bar might also reference the lookup table via the primary key, however it is restricted to values of 'bar_type'. The foreign key does not reflect this, which is why I want to add it in.

Comment: that's not something foreign keys are for. FK's just ensure that every child record has a matching parent record. If you want to ensure proper linkages like that, you should have insert/update triggers to check the validity. Normally you'd use a constraint for that, but since mysql doesn't support them, triggers are the next option.